# Total Active Monitors

Tags: powershell

Im writing a power shell script to set display settings.

Im currently trying to find how many active displays are connected. For example, see if a pc has one monitor or more than 2 etc.

So far I have `(Get-CimInstance Win32_VideoController).Count` although that just shows how many video outputs that I have, not how many are currently being used/ connected.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmicoreprov/wmimonitorid the wmi class for this resides in the namespace root/wmi.

To get this information you can use

```
Get-WmiObject -Namespace 'root/wmi' -Class WmiMonitorID
```

or

```
Get-CimInstance -Namespace 'root/wmi' -ClassName WmiMonitorID
```

this should return information about all connected monitors (including the serialnumber, manufacturer etc)